# Why do we need to copy the Google Play Services library in our project?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Why does Google have this note? [[ref](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)]
What is the harm in adding reference to the library in the SDK directory? I have done it and my app worked just fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it directly from there. I used to do it too till i realized what the problem could be.

If you are making no changes to the library it should work fine. But if you plan to add some build files or configuration etc you should copy it to the project. (I had some for my ant builds) If you dont have any, **at the time of updating the library from SDK manager you lose everything you changed or configured.** Apparently it deletes all unidentified or manually added stuff when updating the library.

With Android studio it is much simpler and you just add a dependency with required version to your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it could will change name in some sdk updates, so if you referece to your copy nothing can go wrong.

instead reference it on gradle to avoid this problem (Gradle work for us to avoid dependecy problem :)).